# Does IBM MobileFirst support native C#/Xaml apps for windows phone 8.1/windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, ibm-mobilefirst

To further clarify the title.
I don't mean HTML5 hybrid apps or apps that have been developed for windows 8/ windows phone 8 and run on windows 8.1/ windows phone 8.1

I would like to know if IBM MobileFirst supports native apps written for windows 8.1 and/or windows phone 8.1 .
For example a universal app.

From what I have read and the tutorials I've seen there is no way to generate dlls for windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@corus I was able to reproduce your problem consistently! What fixed was the changing the build action of the wlclient.properties file to Content.

- Go to solution explorer

  Right click on wlclient.properties and select "Properties"

  Set the "Build action" property to "Content" (this is missing in the knowledge center)

  Also set the "Copy to output directory" to "always"

This should fix the crash issue.

Comment: Ajay, this should be address in an APAR for a future iFix?

Comment: This, combined with trying to connect twice, as jayakarthik said, seems to solve the problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @IdanAdar yes - the doc needs to be fixed and the exception handled with a proper error message instead of an app crash.

Comment: Follow on comment - this crash issue is now fixed in 7.0 . If for some reason the properties file is not found - you get a proper exception instead of a crash

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the IBM MobileFirst Platform Developer Center or the IBM MobileFirst Platform Knowledge Center? you'll find your answers there...

Windows Phone 8 - There are tutorials for Native Windows Phone 8.x development (more to come in the future).

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-native-wp8-development-6-3/
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_native_apps_wp8.html

Windows 8 - Native Windows 8 support is also available (but not yet mentioned in the dev center)

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_native_apps_w8.html

Search the Knowledge Center for more information...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for providing the above resources even though I had already read them. In the knowledge center there is no mention of developing native c#/xaml apps for win 8.1 or wp 8.1, only for win 8 and wp 8. So from my understanding there is no support for these platforms at the moment. The only way would be to develop for win8 and take advantage of the backwards compatibility of windows to run the apps in win8.1

Answer (score 0):

@corcus Part 1 - Currently upto IBM MF 6.3 - there is no formal support in the product UI but we have been qualifying Visual Studio 2013 in the meanwhile (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/ibm_worklight_and_microsoft_visual_studio_2013?lang=en)

Part 2 - our current WindowsPhone8 environment is Silverlight based. What you can try doing is Create a native app with Windows8 environment (this will create a C# app). Open it in VS2013 and then add a Windows Phone 8.1 project to it. Then add the DLL references to the phone project and copy the assets to the Phone Project (or Shared Project) and try running on the Win 8.1 phone. This should work (I have tried Hybrid and it works, but not native - hence not saying conclusively)

Comment: I have tried something simpler yet similar to what you describe. I created a native win8.1 app in VS. Then created a native api with windows8 environment in eclipse (like the tutorials). I copied the dlls and added the references, the pri and the wlclient.properties to the C# win8.1 project and it compiled ok.

Then i copied the code from the "starter application" sample and tried to run it. I got the error "wlServerProtocol property not found in wlclient.properties. Add the wlServerProtocol property to the wlclient.properties file." and the app crashed. Same happened in wp8.1

Comment: The error message cannot be accurate since my wlclient.properties file is this 

wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = 192.168.1.113
wlServerPort = 10080
wlServerContext = /StarterApplication/
wlAppId = NativeWin8
wlAppVersion = 1.0
wlEnvironment = Windows8native
wlPlatformVersion = 6.3.0.0
#languagePreferences = Add locales in order of preference (e.g. fr, en, pt-BR)
#wlMPNSServiceName = Add the MPNS service name for authenticated push.

From debugging i have seen that the wlclient.properties is now correctly read in win8.1. The same code in wp8 works fine
Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: This is a known issue which will be fixed in subsequent releases. But when connect is attempted second time it works. Can you try reconnecting after you get the  error message?

Comment: @jayakarthik Thanks for your comment. The problem is that the app crashes after the error is shown with an unhandled Exception. The debugger message is "An unhandled win32 exception occured in NativeWin8.exe" This is the code that throws the exception

 try
            {
                WLClient client = WLClient.getInstance();
                client.connect(new MyConnectResponseListener(this));
            }
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
            }

It's a basic attempt to connect to the server from the starter application sample.

Comment: @corcus - what version of IBM MF are you using? because this approach will work only with the Windows8 native SDK from 6.3 version. (the WindowsPhone8 SDK is Silverlight based)

Comment: Hi @AjayChebbi and thanks for the answer again. I am using the 6.3 version.

Comment: @corcus the basic problem is that the app is crashing on connect. Please open a PMR.